# C++: struct automatically compiled in namespace

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, header-files

I'm using the d3dx9.h header to be able to use many of the Direct3D functions and datatypes. One of which is 'D3DXVECTOR3'. I have stumbled upon a weird issue of which I can't find the cause:

I have two files, Link.h and Link.cpp. Link is a static class. In my Link.cpp and Link.h I have included the d3dx9.h file as follows:

```
#ifndef D3DX9_INCLUDED
#define D3DX9_INCLUDED
#include <d3dx9.h> // Direct3D 9
#endif
```

In Link.cpp I have created a function to get a D3DXVECTOR3 variable:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef D3DX9_INCLUDED
#define D3DX9_INCLUDED
#include <d3dx9.h> // Direct3D 9
#endif
namespace Core
{
    static class Link
    {
    private:

    public:
        static struct D3DXVECTOR3 getVector()
    };

}
```

My Link.h script makes this public:

```
static struct D3DXVECTOR3 getVector();
```

Now, when I call this function from outside this class it keeps giving me the error

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'Core::D3DXVECTOR3'
```

This is how I call the getVector function:

```
Core::Link::getVector();
```

I get the error even though D3DXVECTOR3 is not a member of 'Core'. I have included d3dx9.h the same way outside this class.

I have tried exactly the same with standard datatypes such as a bool, worked like a charm. Why does getVector return a D3DXVECTOR3 as a child of Core?

Comment: `static struct D3DXVECTOR3 getVector();`  You need to post the Link.h code.  The keyword `static` has several meanings in C++, and it isn't clear which meaning of `static` is implemented by posting that single line.  Also, there is no need to specify `struct` -- that is a holdover from 'C'.

Comment: I've added the relevant Link.h code. I want Link not to be an object, but a class I can directly communicate with, which is the reason why I made the class static. Previously I've been getting errors when not specifying `struct` but after trying now it didn't give me additional errors so I removed it.

Comment: 'static class Foo' isn't a thing in C++, not sure if it's a Windows extension or something.

Comment: My bad! I'm still getting to know C++. I've removed static and it didn't add any additional errors.

Comment: A couple of things. First, the declarations (ie the class MumbleLink block) should be in the header file, not the cpp file. This header file is what will be being included by other code that wants to use this method. For simplicity you may want to also define the method there (as in, write the code the method will perform when called). Second, putting that line in Link.h doesn't make it public, that's what the 'public' keyword in the class declaration does.

Comment: No problem. I keep hitting enter when I mean to put newline so these comments are coming at you half baked.

Comment: Check out http://ideone.com/P0iq0F. Obviously I can't include the d3dx header so I'm not much help with your question, but that should at least help with the formatting issues

Comment: Okay, I've adapted my code to be structured the same as the code you posted. I've tested a function that exactly looks like the getVector function, with the only difference the return type. With standard data types, I've tested int, float and bool, it works perfectly. But like before, as soon as I change it to a struct like D3DXVECTOR3 it thinks it's a child of the Core namespace and says I'm using an undefined type 'Core::D3DXVECTOR3'...